# Are there ready-to-use libraries and frameworks to include JavaScript into Java widgets?

Tags: java, javascript, frameworks, widget

Are there ready-to-use libraries and frameworks to include JavaScript into Java widgets?

something more than just raw WebView widget, the solution where interaction of UI element of Java and JavaScript widgets and logic is highly integrated.

I need to create [IDE for Node.js using Java](https://github.com/Nodeclipse) and [JavaScript](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/JavaScriptContainer) code bases.